# How do I get the default font from the command line?

Tags: fonts, command-line

How can I get the name of the default font (and default monospace font), in the format:

```
Ubuntu Mono:size=12:antialias=false
```

I'm aware of `fc-list` which gives me a list of all the fonts, but how can I know which one is the default font?

Use: I'm trying to launch `xterm` like this: `xterm -fa Ubuntu Mono:size=12:antialias=false` and auto-detect the default monospace font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, substituing `monospace-font-name` with `font-name` if you want the normal font instead:

```bash
# for normal font:
# font="$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name)"

# for monospace font:
font="$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name)"

font="${font//\'}"
font_name="${font% *}"
font_size="${font##* }"

echo "The font is:"
echo "$font_name:size=$font_size:antialias=false"
```

Comment: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface` + tab